# ¿Cómo hacer consultas sobre celdas de una fila de una tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql

Me gustaría probar por filas el valor de las celdas de una tabla. Por ejemplo una tabla TRIANGLE con tres columnas y numeros.

[image: tres columnas con numeros]

Traté de inspirarme con la [respuesta de Laurence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202198/sql-how-to-get-specific-value-of-cell), sin éxito.

```
SELECT @a := A,@b :=B,@c :=C FROM TRIANGLE
    IF ((@a==@b AND @a==@c) OR (@a==@b AND @b==@c)) THEN
        'Guapa'
    IF (@a==@b OR @a==@c OR @c==@b) THEN
        'Bueno'
    IF (@a+@c<@b OR @a+@b<@c) THEN
        'Que es esto ?'
```

Uso mySQL pero estoy muy abierto a otros gestor de base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no te entendí mal, tienes una confusión en la forma en que se trabaja en SQL, no es un tema del motor, todos trabajan igual. Cuando defines y llenas una variable, por ejemplo así:

```
SELECT @a:= A, @b:=B, @c:=C FROM TRIANGLE
```

simplemente estás dejando en cada una de ellas el valor correspondiente a la última fila de la consulta, por que las variables son atómicas y no pueden ser colecciones o arreglos.  Lo que en realidad deberías hacer es verificar la condición directamente en la consulta.

```
SELECT  A,
        B,
        C, 
        CASE WHEN (A = B AND A = C) OR (A = B AND B = C) THEN 'Guapa'
             WHEN (A = B OR A = C OR C = B)              THEN 'Bueno'
             WHEN (A + C < B or A + B < C)               THEN 'Que es esto ?'
             ELSE 'Condición no controlada'
        END  AS 'Resultado'
        FROM TRIANGLE;
```

Usamos la sentencia `CASE WHEN <CONDICION> THEN <VALOR> ELSE <CONDICION NO CONTROLADA>`

La salida sería:

```
|  A |  B |  C |               Resultado |
|----|----|----|-------------------------|
| 20 | 20 | 23 |                   Bueno |
| 20 | 20 | 20 |                   Guapa |
| 20 | 21 | 22 | Condición no controlada |
| 13 | 14 | 30 |           Que es esto ? |
```